# How can I join an array using Google Guava (Java)?

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to join `int[]` (array of int) using Google Guava's Joiner class.

Example:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
String s = Joiner.on(", ").join(array);  // not allowed
```

I checked StackOverflow and Google.  There is no "one-liner" in foundation classes to convert `int[]` to `Integer[]` or `List<Integer>`.  It always requires a for loop, or your own hand-rolled helper function.

Any advice?

Comment: yeah, me too, but I think we're stuck.

Comment: Don't post the answer as part of the question. Post it as an answer (and accept it).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Ints](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) is a Guava library containing helper functions.

Given `int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 }` you can use the following:

```
String s = Joiner.on(", ").join(Ints.asList(array));
```

Or more succinctly:

```
String s = Ints.join(", ", array);
```

Comment: You can even static import, so this is just `String s = Joiner.on(", ").join(asList(array));`

Answer (score 23):

Static method `Ints.join(String separator, int... array)` should also work.

Comment: Javadoc: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#join%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29

Answer (score 0):

The reason they did not add a signature for `join(int[])` is that then they would have had to add one for each primitive type. Since autoboxing works automatically to convert `Integer` to `int` you can pass in an `Integer[]`.

As you said, use `Ints.asList(array)` to get an `Iterable<Integer>` from your `int[]`.

Comment: I don't think autoboxing lets you convert int[] to Integer[].